# Cast field via reflection to array type in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, casting

I want to get private field of array of TextView via reflection, but I need to cast this field back to the array.

```
Field f= FieldUtils.getDeclaredField(ContentAdapter.ViewHolder.class, "button_massive", true);
```

Explicit cast like this  `TextView[] f1 = ((TextView[]) f)` don't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the error when you try that cast? Is using reflection really necessary? I would prefer that as last resort.

Comment: Inconvertible types, it won't compile, I'm using reflection for testing, that's why it's necessary

Answer (score 1):

You're directly typecasting the `Field` type to array. That certainly won't work. What you want is to get the value of `f`, using `Field#get()` method. And then typecast that result to `Object[]`.

```
Field f= FieldUtils.getDeclaredField(ContentAdapter.ViewHolder.class, "button_massive", true);
Object[] result = (Object[]) f.get(obj);
```

If you really want `TextView` type array, then you've to create the array using and populate it from above `Object[]`:

```
TextView[] f1 = new TextView[result.length];
// Iterate over the `Object` array, and populate `f1` array.
```

I haven't tested this out, but it should be working.